# PostgreSQL upsert: do nothing if fields don't change

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Is it possible to express an upsert query, where nothing happens if the inserted data doesn't have any changes compared to what is already in the database?

Currently I have:

```
insert into feeds (link, title, category)
values (...)
on conflict (link)
do update set (title, category, _updated)
= (..., now()::timestamp)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add a `where` clause to the `update` part:

```
insert into feeds (link, title, category)
values (...)
on conflict (link)
do update 
   set (title, category, _updated) = (..., now()::timestamp)
where (feeds.title, feeds.category) is distinct from (excluded.title, excluded.category)
```

Comment: I have a returning statement at the bottom of my query: returning feed_uuid. When I insert a new record or when one of the fields change, it returns an id. But it returnings nothing when nothing is inserted/updated. What would be a solution to this?

Comment: @MichielBorkent - where you able to find a way to do this without having to make a separate SELECT query after?

Comment: What select query @PBandJen?